# how can I make a function run permanently on the website?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function where you can check the status of orders with all orders that have status 1 and the last update was more than 5 days ago and will be canceled and send an email.

I thought about entering a page and that page starts to execute a loop, but shortly after closing the web page it stops running the function and stops making updates to the database, that is, it doesn't run anything.

this is my code:

```
$x = 0;
while ($x < 3) {

    $x = $x + 1;
    $dias1 = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(5);
    $dias2 = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(15);

    $encomendasnaopagas = encomendas::where('estado', 1)->where('updated_at', '<', $dias1)
        ->join('distritos', 'encomendas.distrito', '=', 'distritos.id')
        ->update(['estado' => 5]);
    sleep(5);


    **code to email *** //I don't put it because it's unnecessary code

 $x = $x - 1;
}
```

it works, makes updates whenever I change the values in the database from 5 to 5 seconds but if you close the browser it stops, and I wanted it to be always running after starting it

Comment: Hey, in laravel you can run code in the background and at specific times with: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling

Comment: You need to create Cron job - script running at the equal specified time intervals. Example explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php In Laravel you can also use Task scheduling, which is an adapter for cron.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling

Comment: PHP has max execution time for scripts which is set to 30 seconds by default. You must check other solutions, look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Job script for that and run it with supervisord (PHP Command Line).

Here's an example of a simple Job script.

```
/**
 *
 * Example of creating simple Jobs in PHP that can be kept alive with Supervisord
 *
 * The idea is to keep your logic within an endless loop and make the script sleep for several seconds/minutes within that loop.
 *
 */

if (!empty($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])){
    die('Can only be run with PHP CLI!');
}

while(true) {

    echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ": Running steady!\n";

    sleep(10);

}
```

Next you'll have to tell supervisor to keep this script running or restart it on failure. Below is an example. You'll have to consult the [supervisor documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html) for the settings best suitable to you.

```
/**
 *
 * Example of the corresponding Supervisord worker settings (Local environment)
 *
 * /etc/supervisor.d/test-worker.conf
 *
 */

[program:test-worker]
command=php /var/www/website/jobs/test.job.php
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs=1
priority=999
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=1
startretries=3
user=apache
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/website/worker-test.log
```